# Elixir - Starting Agent to test

Tags: elixir

I'm testing an endpoint to a ReST Api and the I'm storing the api key on an Agent which then I proceed to get the key from, I first added the Agent to a supervision tree and it was working but now I removed it because I expect people to use this code and I want them to supervise the Agent by themselves (If it should not be like that, let me know) and now I'm trying to test the endpoints and I'm getting a 403 status code which obviously tells me that it's not picking the api key from the Agent, I'm using ExUnit and I tried to use `setup_all` callback but I was getting the same error. I didn't pass context or something because how I said, I'm getting the key from the Agent state. I used the `setup_all` callback as follows:

```
setup_all do
  Module.start_link()
end
```

Perhaps I need to pass something else or just initialize it with the Supervisor?

EDIT:

The code that was working with the supervisor before was just a simple supervisor:

```
import Supervisor.Spec

children = [
  worker(Valvex, [])
]

Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one) # Obviously this is not the whole module.
```

The code for the module's `start_link` is just:

```
  def start_link do
    start_link(Application.get_env(:valvex, :token, System.get_env("STEAM_TOKEN")))
  end

  def start_link(key) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> key end, name: __MODULE__)
  end
```

And weirdly the error code changed, I'm not getting a 403 now. I didn't touch anything and I'm getting this error now

```
(RuntimeError) expected ExUnit callback in ValvexTest to return :ok | keyword | map, got #PID<0.207.0> instead
```

Comment: Can you post the Supervisor code that was working? And the code for your  module's `start_link`? And does this `setup_all` code work or throw an error? Why are you getting a 403 error if the agent is down? If you ask for the state of an Agent which is down, the code should throw an error.

Comment: @Dogbert I updated the question. Somehow I'm not getting 403's anymore... The `setup_all` callback is the same as before.

Comment: Try returning `:ok` from `setup_all`. You're currently returning a PID. Just add `:ok` after the line `Module.start_link()`.

Comment: @Dogbert oh, yeah... That was it, it totally went over my head and I didn't read the error message carefully... thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExUnit expects `setup_all` to return one of `:ok`, a keyword list, or a map. This value is merged with the returned values of all other `setup_all` and `setup` blocks and passed to each test as the context. If you don't want to add anything to the context, you can just add a `:ok` after your `Module.start_link()` line:

```
setup_all do
  Module.start_link()
  :ok
end
```

You might want to assert that the Agent started successfully, in which case you can do:

```
setup_all do
  {:ok, _pid} = Module.start_link()
  :ok
end
```